# random.randrange does not seem quite random

Tags: python, random

I am pretty new to python so i dont know many things.
So lets say i got this piece of code

```
for i in range(10000):
n = random.randrange(1, 1000**20)
ar.append(n)
print(n)
```

The smallest number i get out of the 10000 is always 3-4 digits smaller than 1000^20
in this particular example the smallest numbers are

```
2428677832187681074801010996569419611537028033553060588
8134740394131686305349870676240657821649938786653774568
44697837467174999512466010709212980674765975179401904173
50027463313770628365294401742988068945162971582587075902
61592865033437278850861444506927272718324998780980391309
71066003554034577228599139472327583180914625767704664425
90125804190638177118373078542499530049455096499902511032
100371114393629537113796511778272151802547292271926376588
```

i have tried multiple ranges on multiple occasions and every time i get the same results.Maybe i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it so strange that around 1 in 10,000 of the generated values are approximately 1/10,000th the size of the maximum value?

Comment: Since 10,000 is 10**4, I fail to see how this is surprising.

Comment: Why don't you work out the probability of seeing these values as opposed to smaller ones?

Comment: Would you be surprised to see the value `1` pop up? Nevertheless, the chance of that is *exactly* the same as, say, the `2428677832187681074801010996569419611537028033553060588` in your list.

Comment: @RadLexus This seems to be a red-herring. OP's question had to do with the *length*  of the returned number. The probability of a 1-digit number being returned is vanishingly small, whereas the probability of a number with the same length as `2428677832187681074801010996569419611537028033553060588` being returned is not.

Comment: @johncoleman That's only half the story. The other half is the distribution of numbers. In the range `[0,10^n)`, 90% of numbers have `n` digits, 9% have `n-1` digits and so on.

Comment: @Dunes, you're right, that's a far better explanation. The lengths of the results are logarithmic. (But I think your `n`s are off by 1. There is only *one* possible result with length `n`.)

Comment: yeah i didnt took the time to think i just assumed i did something wrong staight away , but thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so let's use small numbers to illustrate that clearly.

Suppose you pick a random number from 1 to 100, inclusively.

How many 1 digit numbers are there? 9, from 1 to 9. For 2 digits it's from 10 to 99, 90 numbers. For 3 digits it's just 1, 100. Since it's a random pick, the probability of picking one of those 100 (9 + 90 + 9) numbers is equal, and it should be intuitively clear it's 1/100. But since there are 90 2-digit numbers, the probability of picking a 2-digit number is 90/100, or 9/10. For 1-digit numbers it's 9/100, and for the only 3-digit one it's 1/100.

I hope that answers the question.

Comment: oh i never thought of it like that. Thanks!